# How to `uniq -c` a sorted vec in rust and iterate the count and value

Tags: rust

Below is pseudo code, of course it doesn't work as expected. I want to use an iterator to iterate each element and the number of occurrences

```
fn main() {
  let a = vec![1,1,2,3,3,3];
  
  for (value, count) in a.iter1(){
      println!("{value}\t{count}")  
      // 1, 2
      // 2, 1
      // 3, 3
  }
  
    for (value, count) in a.iter2().rev(){
      println!("{value}\t{count}")  
      // 3, 3
      // 2, 1
      // 1, 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.12.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) method from [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools). Similar to `uniq -c`, it can only group consecutive elements together.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3];

    for (value, group) in &a.iter().group_by(|&&x| x) {
        let count = group.count();
        println!("{value}\t{count}")
        // 1, 2
        // 2, 1
        // 3, 3
    }
    
    println!("---");

    for (value, group) in &a.iter().rev().group_by(|&&x| x) {
        let count = group.count();
        println!("{value}\t{count}")
        // 3, 3
        // 2, 1
        // 1, 2
    }
}
```